# python set of tuple intersection

Tags: python, join, set

If I have two sets of tuples, is there a way to get the intersection only matching on the first element of the tuple?

I would be able to specify this at set/frozenset creation time if need be.

If it helps, I am trying to do a JOIN on two sets of tuple based on the first values in the tuples

Comment: What if there are two intersecting sets with different first elements?

Comment: what did you do so far?

Comment: What is the expected output of joining `{("A", 23), ("B", 15)}` and `{("X", 23), ("B", 42)}`?

Comment: @Kevin {("B",42)} (I don't care which side of the join I get by default, I can just reorder to get the side I want)

Comment: @yoopoo, I can get the number of intersections by creating sets containing just the first members of each tuple, and then using intersection. The problem is that this does not get me the other data associated with that "key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first_set, second_set = {("A", 23), ("B", 15)}, {("X", 23), ("B", 42)}

# Group items based on the first elements, as dictionaries
d1, d2 = {}, {}
for item in first_set:
    d1.setdefault(item[0], []).append(item)
for item in second_set:
    d2.setdefault(item[0], []).append(item)

# Merge the dictionaries to form a list of grouped items
s = [d1.get(key, []) + d2.get(key, []) for key in d1.viewkeys() | d2]

# Filter out all the groups if the length is lesser than 1
print [item for item in s if len(item) > 1]
# [[('B', 15), ('B', 42)]]
```

Comment: At this point, isn't it easier to just create two sets of the first elements, a dictionary for the rest of the data, and then use the built in intersection, and just use the resulting keys?

Comment: @soandos Why to complicate things when you can do the same with dictionaries? ;)

Comment: Dictionaries don't support intersections

Comment: @soandos Or do they? ;-) I am doing set union on the keys now, if we just change `|` to `&`, it will be set intersection on the dictionary keys

Comment: So its possible to do intersection/union from keys to a dictionary?

Comment: @soandos It will get items from both the sides.